# List-Unsubscribe in header prevents email from being delivered to gmail

Tags: gmail, phpmailer

I am using phpmailer to send email.

When I add the list-unsubscribe the email gets delivered to all accounts, except gmail. It just gets dropped, it doesn't go into spam, it just never arrives at the gmail account. When I remove the list-unsubscribe, it successfully gets sent to the gmail account.

This is the list-unsubscribe that I am using:

```
List-Unsubscribe:<http://keepity.com>,<mailto:admin@keepity.com>
```

This is how its called in phpmailer:

```
$mail->AddCustomHeader("List-Unsubscribe:<http://keepity.com>,<mailto:admin@keepity.com>");
```

This is the full function that calls phpmailer. If I comment out the list-unsubscribe then the mail gets delivered to gmail account, otherwise it never arrives. Does anyone know why it would not be delivered?

```
static function phpmailer_sendmail($mail,$from,$fromAlias,$to,$replyTo,$replyToAlias,$subject,$html,$text) {

    require_once (JPATH_COMPONENT.DS.'PHPMailer-master/class.phpmailer.php');

    $mail = new PHPMailer(true); // by setting TRUE you enable exceptions
    $mail->IsSMTP(true); // SMTP

    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;  // SMTP authentication
    $mail->Mailer = "smtp";

    $mail->Host= "xyz"; // Amazon SES
    $mail->Port = 465;  // SMTP Port
    $mail->Username = "xyz";  // SMTP  Username
    $mail->Password = "xyz";  // SMTP Password

    $mail->ClearAllRecipients(); 
    $mail->ClearAddresses();
    $mail->ClearCCs();
    $mail->ClearBCCs();
    $mail->ClearReplyTos();
    $mail->ClearAttachments();
    $mail->ClearCustomHeaders();
    $mail->SetFrom($from, $fromAlias);
    $mail->AddReplyTo($replyTo,$replyToAlias);
    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->IsHTML(true);  
    $mail->Body    = $html;
    $mail->AltBody = $text;
    $address = $to;
    $addressAlias = $to;
    $mail->AddAddress($address, $addressAlias);
    $mail->AddCustomHeader("List-Unsubscribe:<http://keepity.com>,<mailto:admin@keepity.com>"); 
    $mail->Send();



}
```

Comment: This is strange, since Gmail specifically **recommends** putting a `List-Unsubscribe` header in the email at http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=81126#unsub

Answer (score 11):

the function addCustomHeader gets 2 arguments 
and the unscribe value format should be

```
  <email_to_unscribe@email.com>, <http://url_to_unscribe.com>
```

here is an example how it should be called :

```
  $mail->addCustomHeader("List-Unsubscribe",'<admin@keepity.com>, <http://keepity.com/?email='.$address.'>');
```

Comment: hello, it seem to be better ton add mailto: in the first param ? https://litmus.com/blog/the-ultimate-guide-to-list-unsubscribe    $mail->addCustomHeader("List-Unsubscribe",'<mailto:admin@keepity.com>, <http://keepity.com/?email='.$address.'>'); is that right ?

Answer (score 5):

I know this is old, but it's ranking well in Google for a search of "List-Unsubscribe" and the provided suggestion isn't quite correct.

PHPmailer addCustomHeader only takes one argument. The double quotes wrap the entire header like this.

```
$mail->AddCustomHeader("List-Unsubscribe: <mailto:info@example.com?subject=Unsubscribe>, <http://example.com/unsubscribe.php?mailid=1234>");
```

List-Unsubscribe takes 2 arguments, a mailto: and a URL that can be set up to automatically unsubscribe the email. Of course you can generate the mailid (or whatever you call the GET var) dynamically too.

Comment: As of 26. November 2018, `addCustomHeader` actually does take two parameters: https://hotexamples.com/examples/-/PHPMailer/addCustomHeader/php-phpmailer-addcustomheader-method-examples.html